# Accumulation points ,Derived sets

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I have come up with a proof of the following statement, but I am not sure if I am correct . 
Prove:If p is a limit point of a set A , then p is also a limit point of A/{p}.
Proof:We need to show that every open set G containing p , contains a point of A/{p} different from p , i.e. G open ,p element of G implies (G/{p}) intersect (A/{p}) does not equal {  } . Case 1 :p is not an element of A. Then A/{p}=A , and so (G/{p}) intersect (A/{p}) =(G/{p}) intersect (A ) does not equal {  },since p is a limit point of A.Case 2 : p is an element of A. Then we have again (G/{p}) intersect (A/{p}) does not equal {  } . for if (G/{p}) intersect (A/{p}) = { } , then G intersect (A) ={p} , so that p is not a limit point of A contrary to assumption.Therefore p is also a limit point of A/{p}.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting observation.  Here is a quick proof.
If p is a limit point of A and G is an open nhood of p,
then (A - {p}) $\cap$ (G - {p}) = A $\cap$ (G - {p}) is not empty.
Thus p is a limit point of A - {p}.

Comment: So is my proof correct Mr Elliot??

Comment: Yes, it is correct.  However the first case is not needed so I'd mark it down for redundancy.